# PL/SQL adding more characters to string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to be able to created a small report at the end of a procedure and send it via email to myself.

So I have a function that returns what it did in form of a string:

```
create or replace function  TEST_DELETE_ME RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
COUNTS INT;
begin

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO COUNTS FROM MV;

  IF COUNTS = 0  THEN
      RETURN 'MV is empty';
  ELSE
      RETURN 'MV has been refreshed today';
  END IF;
end;
/
```

then I have a procedure that calls this function and stores returned results into varchar2 variable:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TEST2_DELETEME
authid current_user
IS
    report_stats  VARCHAR2(4000);  
    today varchar(30);
BEGIN
    select to_char(sysdate, 'Month DD, YYYY') into today  from dual;

    report_stats := 'Load Statistics for: ' || today || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
    report_stats := TEST_DELETE_ME;
    report_stats := 'End of Report!' || CHR(13) || CHR(10); 
    utl_mail.send( sender => 'refresh_mvs@orcl.com', 
    recipients => 'angelina12@gmail.com',
    subject => 'message from angelina',  message => report_stats);
END;
```

When I executed this:
EXECUTE TEST2_DELETEME;

I received email with only what the function returned:

```
MV is empty
```

How do I combine all these string into `report_stats` variable?

In case you wonder what `CHR(13) || CHR(10);` does...

It adds a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting report_stats again and again. To extend it use:

report_stats := report_stats || 'whatever';

Comment: I need to go with this approach because I will be assigning more characters to this string in many different places in the procedure

Comment: as I was looking at your answer, I realized that :) Thanks a lot! I know I can always count on you guys...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
report_stats := 'Load Statistics for: ' || today || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
      'End of Report!' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || TEST_DELETE_ME;
```

Answer (score 0):

:= is an assignment operator not a concat operator (as +=)...each time you call `report_stats := XX` you are overwriting the existing value.

try

```
report_stats := 'Load Statistics for: ' || today || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
report_stats := report_stats ||'End of Report!' || CHR(13) || CHR(10); 
report_stats := report_stats ||TEST_DELETE_ME;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TEST2_DELETEME
authid current_user
IS
    report_stats  VARCHAR2(4000);  
    today varchar(30);
BEGIN
    select to_char(sysdate, 'Month DD, YYYY') into today  from dual;

    report_stats := report_stats || 'Load Statistics for: ' || today || CHR(13) || CHR(10);
    report_stats := report_stats || 'End of Report!' || CHR(13) || CHR(10); 
    report_stats := report_stats || TEST_DELETE_ME;
    utl_mail.send( sender => 'refresh_mvs@orcl.com', 
    recipients => 'angelina12@gmail.com',
    subject => 'message from angelina',  message => report_stats);
END;
```

Output:

```
"Load Statistics for: May 30, 2014
End of Report!
MV is empty"
```